# ¿Porque el scanf no me funciona?

Tags: c

estoy empezando en esto de la programación y tengo un problema en un programa que intento hacer muy básico. Todo me funciona pero al momento de ejecutarlo el programa no me deja escribir ni nada. Quiero aclarar que el programa no hace falta de declaraciones globales.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main() 
{
   int var=5; 
   float var1, var2, var3; 

   printf("Este mensaje se imprime \n"); 
   printf("%d \n", var); 

   scanf("%f", &var1); /
   scanf("%f %f", &var2, &var3);

   printf("%d %f %f %f", var, var1, var2, var3);
}
```

Comment: Quita el `/`, y especifica el tipo de `main`-> `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

Deberías tener en cuenta que la función principal `main` no tiene declarado el tipo de retorno ni tiene la sentencia `return`. La correcta implementación de tu código sería la siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int var = 5;
   float var1, var2, var3;

   printf("Este mensaje se imprime \n");
   printf("%d \n", var);

   scanf("%f", &var1);
   scanf("%f %f", &var2, &var3);

   printf("%d %f %f %f", var, var1, var2, var3);

   return 0;
}
```

Además, tienes un caracter "colgado" en la línea 11 de tu código (el caracter '\') y eso te generará un error.

En escencia, creo que simplemente es eso. Agregando lo que te indiqué, a mí me funciona.

Como recomendación, procura la próxima vez anexar los errores que obtienes por parte del compilador para tener una mejor perspectiva del problema y poder ayudarte de mejor forma.

Espero haberte podido solucionar el problema. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, gracias a ti ya funcionó mi programa te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

Usa

```
system("pause")
```

al final de la función y ya no se cerrará abruptamente tu programa